# How can I insert a dynamic URL in my email template?

Tags: urls, buddypress, html, email

I'm not sure if that's even possible, but I thought I should give it a try.

I'm using [WP Better Emails](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-better-emails/) plugin in order to create HTML emails for my buddypress website.

I want to add to the footer an option for the user to change his notification settings. Something like this:
Do you want to update your notification settings? Change Settings.

I need to make 'Change Settings' a dynamic link that it'll redirect user to 'http://connect.stage.tgg.gr/members/%username%/settings/notifications/'

How can I achieve this through HTML? Can I perhaps do it through a filter?

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with this plugin, but it looks like you can add extra template variables with a filter named `'wpbe_tags'`:

```
    function template_vars_replacement( $template ) {
        $to_replace = array(
            'blog_url'         => get_option('siteurl'),
            'home_url'         => get_option('home'),
            'blog_name'        => get_option('blogname'),
            'blog_description' => get_option('blogdescription'),
            'admin_email'      => get_option('admin_email'),
            'date'             => date_i18n(get_option('date_format')),
            'time'             => date_i18n(get_option('time_format'))
        );
        $to_replace = apply_filters('wpbe_tags', $to_replace);

        foreach ( $to_replace as $tag => $var ) {
            $template = str_replace( '%' . $tag . '%', $var, $template );
        }

        return $template;
    }
```

So, this might do the trick:

```
add_filter( 'wpbe_tags', 'wpse_99484_extra_tpl_var' );

function wpse_99484_extra_tpl_var( $to_replace )
{
    $to_replace['username'] = function_to_get_buddy_press_user();
    return $to_replace:
}
```

I am not sure what the correct `function_to_get_buddy_press_user()` is in your situation, it depends on the context of this email.

Comment: Hi @toscho.
I'm not very good with PHP, but I will give it a go.
I want to add a link to get them to their Settings/Notifications page.
I have a link 'Change Settings' that I need to connect to this URL.